# jQuery check each input element

Tags: jquery, html, svg

I have a form with 4 elements, here's one:

```
<form class="frm">
<div class="first-field">
  <input class="text1" type="text" placeholder="Uw naam.." value="">
  <svg version="1.1" class="unfilled" id="svg_user"></svg>
</div>
```

I got the following jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
     $('.text1').keyup(function(){
          if ($(this).val() == '') { //Check to see if there is any text entered
              //If there is no text within the input then add default class 'unfilled'
              $("#svg_user").attr("class", "unfilled");
          } else {
              /*If there is text in the input, then change default
                class 'unfilled' to new class 'filled'.*/
              $("#svg_user").attr("class", "unfilled filled");
          }
     });
});
```

It checks if an input element has been filled and applies a class to the inside SVG element accordingly to the outcome of the function. This works just fine.

But I have 4 input elements and to get it to work I need to give each input element a different class and use the above jQuery code 4 times to work.

There must be a faster en cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Just replace `$('.text1')` with `$('input')` and it will bind the keyup event to all inputs.

Comment: The problem is, if I do that, and I checked this, when the first input is filled, the svg class changes, but as soon as I start typing in the second input, the svg element gets it default class because all input element share the same name. So they are connected and get the same treatment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a common class

```
<div class="first-field">
    <input class="text1 required" type="text" placeholder="Uw naam.." value="" />
    <svg version="1.1" class="unfilled svg_user"></svg>
</div>
```

then

```
$('.required').keyup(function () {
    var $svg = $(this).next();
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $svg.attr("class", "unfilled");
    } else {
        $svg.attr("class", "unfilled filled");
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qtys9t8d/)

Comment: Thnx, but as replied in the above comment, a common class or id will treat each input element the same. So when the first one is filled, the right class is applied, but as soon as i start typing in the second one, and delete that text, the first input element resets aswell, meaning, the default class is applied.

Comment: Wow, your code is working fine, I will try that. Thanks mate!